# Laravel -> Routed Pagination

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started using the Laravel framework and I would like the following (but cannot seem to get it right):

- pagination, not the kind which Laravel explains but more the kind of /about.html - /portfolio.html etc.

It seems really difficult to achieve this, I searched for a bit and could not find anything or perhaps im not using the right search terms.

The HomeController serves the layout view that has all the html.
The default route is:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@show');
```

And this is the HomeControiler:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function show() {
        return View::make('layout');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pagination, it's just more than one route. Your routes for that would be something like:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showIndex');
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@showAbout');
Route::get('/portfolio', 'HomeController@showPortfolio');
```

The corresponding controller might be like:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showIndex() {
        return View::make('index');
    }

    public function showAbout() {
        return View::make('about');
    }

    public function showPortfolio() {
        return View::make('portfolio');
    }

}
```

You definitely don't put the HTML for different routes all in the same view file (shared navigation should be handled via shared layouts and the `@extends` blade keyword), and it's best not to use the `.html` extension when routes are perfectly happy without it.